# Static content change Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

Are there any possibilities to dynamically change the static content?

I have data in the `DataStorage`, while most of the HTML/CSS/JavaScript content and various templates (for `StringTemplate`) are during the servlet deployment copied to static file server. The problem is that none content is purely static – e.g. when customer asks for new icon or change on web page I have to re-deploy the whole servlet, sometimes only because of tiny changes in static HTML.

Is there any ‘FTP like’ storage or other better way how to put the static content on GAE?

Regards,
STeN

Comment: What's wrong with redeploying? This is what the deployment process is for.

Comment: Take it that way - 5 developers work on application Java code. We finalize app, tag it in source repository and we start making the UI nice. From time to time we update look&feel. If any of the developers by mistake puts on the SVN during next years of GAE app living some test or bad Java code I will redeploy - I am in troubles... I need all the time to keep in mind I have to deploy the revision XXX with data YYY. It is hard to maintain simply...

Comment: This is a standard revision control / deployment issue. You need to build a deployment process that supports this, or you'll never be able to do something even as basic as deploying bugfixes.

Comment: Agree, agree... simply take it that way - I do not feel good when I need to compile and deploy 30000 java lines because of some bloody png has to be one pixel smaller... But sure - we weil adopt to use it safely. Thanks for comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Generally people redeploy the entire war. Also be aware that the cdn for appengine is sometimes over zealous about caching and there is no way to manually flush it so if your CSS and JavaScript are changing it may take 10-15 minutes to expire. We sometimes append build numbers to those assets if there is a risk of breaking things.

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for sharing you personal experience. I am just looking on how use of the Google Cloud Storage - would not this help?

Comment: That would mean dividing up your site deployment. How often are these assets changing? Redeployments aren't that big a deal.. We do it with a continuous integration server so it's just a matter of pushing a button.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, no. You simply can't change the static content in your app, because I believe static content is moved to different, more efficient static servers during the deployment itself.

You could always consider serving the content via a dynamic handler - either storing the static content in the datastore or redirecting to different files based on the lastest version. Given your stated use case, where you want CMS like functionality, I think it makes more sense to store those assets in the datastore, preferably also in memcache, and serve them dynamically.

Comment: Hi, so the static files and DataStore are the only possibilities? I do not want to put everything into DataStore - imagine the web page with 50 images, CSS, JavaScript which is partly dynamically rendered - how I will putt this into DataStore? This is extremely limiting disadvantage of GAE

Comment: In your situation, redeployment, though a nuisance to you, is probably the best in terms of efficiency of the app.

Comment: Hi Dave would not Google Cloud Storage help there? From the Google blog: _...Google Storage for developers, a service that lets you store data on Google’s infrastructure with very high reliability, availability and performance. You can use it for your online archives, storing and serving static content (e.g. images and video), sharing data with your customers and partners, as well for use with other Google services like App Engine..._

Comment: If you find this a disadvantage of appengine just wait until you really dig in... Appengine is an experiment (or experience) in tradeoffs.

Comment: @RickMangi While this is technically true, I think the real question is what you're trading off for. If you need the gains that you willing to sacrifice other things for, then it's an excellent platform.

Comment: Agreed which is why my answer here is to just bite the bullet and deploy the app with each asset change.